# How to convert delta quill into PDF?

Tags: flutter, dart, quill, quill-delta

I'm using flutter_quill it's a rich text editor (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_quill), and I'd like to convert data from it into PDF. I've already tried to find some packages but almost all of them are out of date or don't support functionality that I need. Maybe someone already worked with it or have some ideas how it can be done.
Thanks

Comment: Did you get the solution?

Comment: No, not yet. The only solution that I've found is to convert delta_quil to html string and then create pdf with this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html_to_pdf. But I didn't implement it.